# getColumnArray equivalent for parsed JSON object arrays in Smartface.io Framework?

Tags: arrays, json, smartface.io

I got a Json file like;

```
{
"Cities": [
    {
        "Name": "London",            
        "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rome",
        "Country": "ITA"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Antalya",
        "Country": "TR"
    }
]
}
```

How can I get City Names as an array like ["London","Rome","Antalya"] without doing;

```
var tempJSON = JSON.parse(jsonCities);
var arrayCityNames = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tempJSON.Table.length; i++){
    arrayCityNames[i] = tempJSON.Table[i].Name;
}
```

if tempJSON was a Dataset we could use getColumnArray

```
arrayCityNames = Data.Dataset.getColumnArray("Name");
```

Is there any built in method to do this for parsed JSON's?

*Please keep in mind that the question is related to Smartface.io Framework, not jquery itself*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tempJSON = JSON.parse(jsonCities);// here you load your JSON
var arrayCityNames = []; // your output array
var cityArray = tempJSON['Cities']; // enter Cities array
for (var i = 0; i <cityArray.length; i++){ // iterate over your list
    arrayCityNames.push(cityArray[i]['Name']); // add to list name of your city list
}
```